# CMake definition redefinition works only if greater

Tags: cmake

I have a serious issue with a CMake project where I try to redefine a build number variable locally for a unit test, but it just failed once the real build number increased above the hardcoded one of my test.
After some testing, I am absolutely horrified to find that if I do:

```
set(MY_BUILD_NUMBER "3111")
add_definitions(-DMY_BUILD_NUMBER=${MY_BUILD_NUMBER})

...and later for my test I redefine it to a hardcoded value
add_definitions(-DMY_BUILD_NUMBER=3118)
```

The MY_BUILD_NUMBER in my test is 3111, which is logical.

But if I do:

```
set(MY_BUILD_NUMBER "3120")
add_definitions(-DMY_BUILD_NUMBER=${MY_BUILD_NUMBER})

...and later for my test I redefine it to a hardcoded value
add_definitions(-DMY_BUILD_NUMBER=3118)
```

The MY_BUILD_NUMBER in the code is 3120 and *not* 3118 anymore.

I could not find any documentation about this. Does anyone know what can cause such a unexpected behavior of CMake, or if it's just one more bug that to report...
Thanks !

Comment: Are you talking about the cmake variable `MY_BUILD_NUMBER` or the maco `MY_BUILD_NUMBER` which are entirely different things?  Also, what's `INSPECTOR_BUILD_NUMBER`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to rename one variable for my example. Basically, CMake a variable is used to set a C++ definition of the same name to be used in the code.
I think I found the issue: 2 definitions with the same name are given to the compiler, but CMake seem to order all definitions alphabetically when passed to the C++ compiler, causing the order to change between both cases and thus the bigger to be located after, cause the bigger to be used :-(

Comment: "Does anyone know what can cause such a unexpected behavior of CMake" - Not sure what behavior of CMake do you expect, but CMake just passes all definitions to the compiler. So it is up to the compiler to process repeated definition of the same variable. You may build with `make VERBOSE=1` and find out **actual** parameters for a compiler.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I thought CMake would store all definitions in a map and thus not set a same definition twice to the compiler, which would be logical, but no. Otherwise I would expect it to simply copy all the definitions as is, which would work as well, but no, it sorts them alphabetically... I've been trying to understand the logic of CMake for the last 12 years, but it keeps doing the opposite as we would expect, and every detail matters !

Comment: Just tested `make VERBOSE=1` with a toy example: CMake **sorts** `-D` definitions (sorts only definitions of the same macro) and **passes both** of them to the compiler. And the compiler(`gcc`) warns about the macro redefinition. CMake version is 3.16, generator is "Unix Makefiles".

Comment: And this is exactly why you shouldn't define these things on a directory level. Adding this kind of definition to a target avoids these kind of issues unless you add conflicting defines on the same target, which would not make sense anyways...